# ruby add values to string separated by comma except the first element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

```
    device_target = ["3001", "3002", "3003"]
    devices = ",kv1101="
    device_target.map {|d|
      case d
        when "30000" #desktop
          devices << ":9"
        when "30001" # smartphone
          devices << ":3:4:6:8"        
        when "30002" #tablet
          devices << ":2:5:7"
        when "30003" #feature_phone
          devices << ":1"
      end
```

My target is to get `devices = "kv1101=3:4:6:8:2:5:7:1"`. But, how can I avoid this colon `:` from the first entry? The order doesn't matter.

Comment: Please provide valid input and output. The code can't produce `"9:3:4:6:8:2"`.

Comment: I am sure it is just a typo but your "targets" are `3001,3002,3003` so 2 things one there is no `3000` and 2 your case statement will never work since `d` will never be in `30000,30001,30002,30003`

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful to you, consider selecting the one you valued most.

Answer (score 7):

Store the values in an array and then use the `join` method:

```
devices = ",kv1101="
my_devices = []
device_target.map {|d|
  case d
    when "30000" #desktop
      my_devices << "9"
    when "30001" # smartphone
      my_devices += ["3","4","6","8"]
    when "30002" #tablet
      my_devices += ["2","5","7"]
    when "30003" #feature_phone
      my_devices << "1"
  end}
devices << my_devices.join(":")
```

Answer (score 6):

Similar to [Fer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26216819/477037), but using [`flat_map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and its return value:

```
device_target = ['30001', '30002', '30003']
devices = ',kv1101='
devices << device_target.flat_map { |device|
             case device
             when '30000' then 9            # desktop
             when '30001' then [3, 4, 6, 8] # smartphone
             when '30002' then [2, 5, 7]    # tablet
             when '30003' then 1            # feature_phone
             end
           }.join(':')

devices #=> ",kv1101=3:4:6:8:2:5:7:1"
```

Or using a lookup table as [suggested by tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216672/ruby-add-values-to-string-separated-by-comma-except-the-first-element/26216952#comment41208147_26216952):

```
device_target = ['30001', '30002', '30003']
device_map = {
  '30000' => 9,            # desktop
  '30001' => [3, 4, 6, 8], # smartphone
  '30002' => [2, 5, 7],    # tablet
  '30003' => 1             # feature_phone
}

devices = ',kv1101='
devices << device_target.flat_map { |d| device_map[d] }.join(':')
```

Comment: `flat_map` does a great job in this case. Could be even better if instead of a rigid `case` statement it was a lookup table using a Hash.

Comment: A variant of #2: `",kv1101="+device_map.values_at(*device_target).flatten.join(?:)`.

Answer (score -1):

try this out:

```
"kv1101=:3:4:6:8:2:5:7:1".sub(/:/, "")
=> "kv1101=3:4:6:8:2:5:7:1"
```